# Why im getting Win32Exception: The operation completed successfully?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

This is my code just taking a screenshots of the entire screen.
After it's working for few time it's throwing the exception.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

namespace Capture_ScreenShots
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string bfbc;
        string save_location;
        int save_image;
        int screenWidth;
        int screenHeight;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            save_location = @"c:\screenshots\sc1\";
            timer1.Enabled = true;
            timer1.Interval = 200;
            save_image = 0;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            save_image = save_image + 1;
            bfbc = save_location  + save_image.ToString("D3") + ".jpg";

            screenWidth = Screen.GetBounds(new Point(0, 0)).Width;
            screenHeight = Screen.GetBounds(new Point(0, 0)).Height;
            Bitmap bmpScreenShot = new Bitmap(screenWidth, screenHeight);
            Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage((Image)bmpScreenShot);
            gfx.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, new Size(screenWidth, screenHeight));
            bmpScreenShot.Save(bfbc, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        }
    }
}
```

The exception is on the line:

```
gfx.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, new Size(screenWidth, screenHeight));
```

This is the exception message:

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception was unhandled
  HResult=-2147467259
  Message=The operation completed successfully
  Source=System.Drawing
  ErrorCode=-2147467259
  NativeErrorCode=0
  StackTrace:
       at System.Drawing.Graphics.CopyFromScreen(Int32 sourceX, Int32 sourceY, Int32 destinationX, Int32 destinationY, Size blockRegionSize, CopyPixelOperation copyPixelOperation)
       at System.Drawing.Graphics.CopyFromScreen(Int32 sourceX, Int32 sourceY, Int32 destinationX, Int32 destinationY, Size blockRegionSize)
       at Capture_ScreenShots.Form1.timer1_Tick(Object sender, EventArgs e) in d:\C-Sharp\Capture_ScreenShots\Capture_ScreenShots\Capture_ScreenShots\Form1.cs:line 44
       at System.Windows.Forms.Timer.OnTick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Timer.TimerNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
       at Capture_ScreenShots.Program.Main() in d:\C-Sharp\Capture_ScreenShots\Capture_ScreenShots\Capture_ScreenShots\Program.cs:line 18
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Not sure why the exception happen.
It is working fine but only for a very short time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both `BitMap` and `Graphics` implement the IDisposible interface.

You aren't disposing of you object at the end of the method.  The using construct provides an easy way to do this.

Replace your last four lines:

```
        Bitmap bmpScreenShot = new Bitmap(screenWidth, screenHeight);
        Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage((Image)bmpScreenShot);
        gfx.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, new Size(screenWidth, screenHeight));
        bmpScreenShot.Save(bfbc, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

With:

```
        using (Bitmap bmpScreenShot = new Bitmap(screenWidth, screenHeight))
        using (Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage((Image)bmpScreenShot))
        {
            gfx.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, new Size(screenWidth, screenHeight));
            bmpScreenShot.Save(bfbc, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        }
```

The using construct ensures the system resources these classes used are free so you don't run into a conflict down the line.

Answer (score 3):

The message is coming from `NativeErrorCode == 0`, which is indeed no error at all.

To see the actual failure, you will have to look at the HResult field, which is 0x80004005.  Unfortunately, this is an extremely generic failure.

This combination of non-zero HResult and zero NativeErrorCode indicates a failure in a COM component, which directly returns an HRESULT without using SetLastError().

Your only other clue is where the exception occurred.  In this context of graphics processing, it's surely a GDI+ call that failed, since GDI+ is COM-based and GDI is not.